# Как удалить элемент из списка, не добавляя элементы в новй список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Как удалить элемент из списка names, не добавляя элементы в новый список?
При удалении через remove, длина списка уменьшается и цикл перестает правильно работать.

```
from random import randint

 players = 10
 names = ['urmatik', 'beksich', 'aziretich', 'businesswman', 'erjanchik', 'ataichik', 'rasulchik',
          'rusik', 'sanjarchik', 'saidchik']
 w_names = []
 dict1 = {}
 list1 = []
 i = 0


 def twenty_one(names, players: int):
     i = 0
     while i < players:
         print(f'Играет {names[i]}')
         two_cards = randint(2, 11) + randint(2, 11)
         print(two_cards)
         check = input('One more? да/нет')
         while check == 'да':
             two_cards = two_cards + randint(2, 11)
             print(two_cards)
             if two_cards > 21:
                 break
             check = input('One more? да/нет')

         if two_cards > 21:
             two_cards = 0
         if two_cards > 0:
             w_names.append(names[i])
             list1.append(two_cards)
```

Answer (score 2):

можно перестроить список names - добавить поле со статусом игрока, например так:

```
names = [[n, 1] for n in names]
```

тогда имя игрока нужно опрашивать например так:

```
print(f'Играет {names[i][0]}')
```

добавить проверку статуса так:

```
if names[i][1]==1:
```

отключить игрока от раздачи так:

```
names[i][1]=0
```